# Defining method body inside class declaration?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal, delphi

I'm trying to define class methods all inside of the class declaration in Free Pascal, which I haven't been able to find any examples of online. Currently I have to do it like so:

```
unit Characters;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

// Public
interface
type
  TCharacter = class(TOBject)
    private
      FHealth, FAttack, FDefence: Integer;
      procedure SetHealth(newValue: Integer);
    public
      constructor Create(); virtual;
      procedure SayShrek();
      function GetHealth(): Integer;
    published
      property Health: Integer read GetHealth write SetHealth;
    end;


// Private
implementation
    constructor TCharacter.Create;
  begin
    WriteLn('Ogres have LAYERS!');
    end;

  procedure TCharacter.SayShrek;
  begin
    WriteLn('Shrek!');
    end;

  procedure TCharacter.SetHealth(newValue: Integer);
  begin
    FHealth:= FHealth + newValue;
    end;

  function TCharacter.GetHealth() : Integer;
  begin
    GetHealth:= FHealth;
  end;

end.
```

Is there any possible way to make this a little cleaner? Defining everything elsewhere looks messy and is unorganized.

### **EDIT:**

To clarify, I'd like to do something along the lines of this:

```
TMyClass = class(TObject)
    public
      procedure SayHi();
      begin
          WriteLn('Hello!');
      end;
end;
```

Instead of having to define it further down. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not possible in Pascal. It is just not allowed by its grammar.

It is a fundamental design in Pascal that units are divided in `interface` (*What can be done?*) and `implementation` (*How is something done?*).
The compiler reads all `interface` sections before parsing the `implementation` parts. You might know this from C language. `implementation` could be described as *.c-files, whereas `interface` is equivalent to *.h-files in C.

Furthermore such code would heavily decrease readability of `interface` sections (f.i. class declaratons).

What benefits do you hope to get with that?

Comment: Ah, okay. The C explanation helped quite a bit. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not do this. Pascal <strike>has a single-pass compiler</strike> from the outset was designed for the single-pass compilation so you can not use something before it will be declared.

As a simple example in pseudocode:

```
MyClass = class
  procedure MethodA;
  begin
    MethodB; <== At this point the compiler knows nothing about MethodB
  end;
  procedure MethodB;
  begin
  end;
end;
```

It is why each unit have at least two sections: `interface` (declarations, you can think about it as about C++ header files) and `implementation`.

However there are some tricks in the language syntax for implementing cyclic declarations where you can use forward declarations.

For the pointers:

```
PMyRec = ^TMyRec; // Here is TMyRec is not declared yet but compiler can to handle this
TMyRec = record
  NextItem: PMyRec;
end;
```

For the classes:

```
MyClassA = class; // Forward declaration, class will be fully declared later

MyClassB = class
  SomeField: MyClassA;
end;

MyClassA = class
  AnotherField: MyClassB;
end;
```

In the IDE you can use `Shift+Ctrl+Up/Down` keys to navigate between declaration and implementation of the item.

Comment: I was looking to do something more along the lines of:

MyClassA = class
   procedure Test;
   begin
      WriteLn('Test');
   end;
end;

Would that be possible? It seemed like you did have the method body  in your first example there, even though it referenced something not yet defined.

Comment: Define before use is a philosophy. Compilers and number of passes vary. I think FPC has about 5-6 passes. The error generation e.g. is much better this way.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Thanks. It seems I missed something a lot of years ago :) Answer was updated.